# How to prevent abstract method from being called?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a super super (grandparent) abstract bean class calling `loadData()` method in its `init()` method like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFwkPageController extends PageControllerSupport {

    public String init(){
        cleanSession();
        loadData();
        return initNavigation;
    }

    public abstract void loadData();

    // ...
}
```

now I don't want this `loadData()` method to be called in the sub subclass (child). I can't change the super class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide the method, reduce its visibility or prevent anyone from calling.

However you can do something like this in your subclass:

```
@Override
public void loadData() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not supported");
}
```

Alternatively, you could put in an `interface`, exposing only what may be called through the interface.

```
Interface interface = new Implementation();
interface.callMethod();
```

This way you will have complete control.

Answer (score 2):

Override the method and give the new behavior to the child class. You could just

```
@Override 
public void loadData() {
    // do nothing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the calling of the method in children, as the method is public. You could count every method invocation in a private instance variable, and throw an exception, if it has been called more than once (or how many times you expect).

Furthermore you need to mark the method as `final` so children can't override this method and change the behavior.